# How can I deploy a Flask app containing a Kik bot to Heroku? (Python)

Tags: python, flask, heroku, pip, kik

Silly newb question, it seems I can't use git to install content I need in the Heroku console, but my app/bot is dependent on content I normally use that for. I know very little about how git and pip work, or the right terminology to ask a question like this, so bare with me!
I have a bot made with [Tomer8007's Kik Bot API](https://github.com/tomer8007/kik-bot-api-unofficial) that I've embedded in Flask and want to deploy to Heroku. I've deployed Flask sites there before, they work like a charm, but because I import everything to Heroku via git using the Heroku CLI I can't import this one which is already using git.
I normally use these two commands to fetch and install the dependencies I need for that project:

```
git clone -b new https://github.com/tomer8007/kik-bot-api-unofficial
pip install ./kik-bot-api-unofficial
```

I tried manually downloading and installing the API without git, but then it throws this error when I tried to run it: *"TypeError: Couldn't build proto file into descriptor pool: duplicate file name (google/protobuf/descriptor.proto)"*, wheras it works perfectly fine when I use the two above commands instead. (This is locally btw).
I also made an attempt to import to heroku before using those commands and instead using them in the heroku console, but it throws a bunch of errors when I try. I also can't import it after using those commands locally, because I already used git. (I'm not sure how that works though, that's why I'm here.)

Everything in procfile.txt, requirements.txt, runtime.txt, etc is fine, the only issue is getting the API for the Kik bot. I've no idea what's going haywire when I attempt to manually download it instead of using git clone, or what alternative options I have. Any pointers?

Comment: what version of `pip` and `python` are you using? Per the comment in the github repo:
`First, make sure you are using Python 3.6+, not python 2.7. Second, just install it directly from GitHub:`

Comment: @azbarcea I'm using 3.8, as 3.9+ has some issues with this api apparently, which is addressed in one of the bug issues on the github. Im also using the latest version of pip, i use the upgrade pip commands before attempting to install anything.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the `duplicate file name (google/protobuf/descriptor.proto)` error  was caused by a breaking change in the `protobuf` package in versions greater than 4.

This is [now fixed](https://github.com/tomer8007/kik-bot-api-unofficial/commit/090fa258353dccbf2bb0db8012295124aaeb4112), and should [also work on Python 3.9+](https://github.com/tomer8007/kik-bot-api-unofficial/commit/75471620fdbb93061a11c1b31366479509b25022).